# WP-PostRatings : Ratings stopped working still Loading

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure when or why this plugin stopped working, but I recently updated WordPress and many of the other plugins. I'm really not sure if this is what caused the problem, or if it occurred for another reason prior to this update.

All the ratings are showing up, but when you place the cursor over the stars it won't let you select a rating.

Any idea what's going on here???

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/

my web site

[my site](http://p1.b7d.com/m63m/foods/%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A9/)

Comment: have you recently updated this plugin also? Is there any update available to this plugin?

Comment: @alex alex i will update wordpress and the plugin